# Wierd white line in android start activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, user-interface, user-experience

When I changed main activity I started getting this wierd line on start activity, how can I show usuall date time, batter and everything you extect to see at top of screen?

[image]

Comment: because you the for the app or the current activity has white color as `colorPrimaryDark`, Please go through the [Android Theme Concept](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes)

Answer (score 0):

You can set statusbar color with theme.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Please check your theme in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I made stupid mistake and added attribute of noactionbar in manifest